# Notify Icon for Window Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I have developed win service program which reads a excel file from my local drive and then save this file values to database and now I want to develop a notify icon which will be display to show a message("Excel File Saved In Database") after my service will start and will save excel file to database.

Please give me some hints to solve this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Vista onwards, your service will not be allowed to interact with the desktop, so cannot have a UI runnning directly out of the service. You need to build an agent application that starts up at user login that can chat to your service (maybe using WCF).

Here's what [MS have to say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx) about doing this:

> For more complex interactions, developers should move their UI code into an agent that runs in the user’s session and handles all UI requirements. The agent communicates with the service through RPC or named pipes. If the user initiates the UI interaction by using Control Panel, Internet Explorer, or a similar UI experience, that UI experience should start the agent. The agent then handles all UI interactions. If UI is required but is not initiated by the user, the service must request the agent to start any required UI, instead of attempting to launch that UI by itself. In the rare situation where the service must initiate a user interaction and the agent is not already running, the service should call the CreateProcessAsUser API to start the agent. The agent can then initiate all UI interactions. It is important for developers to carefully review all possible usage scenarios and consider moving all UI code into an agent that runs in the user session.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that a windows service runs in the background and has no impact on the user's desktop.

You could create an application similar to this (without the windows form): [Notify Icon control in .Net 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12312/Notify-Icon-control-in-NET-2-0-with-balloon-tips)

And then use something like the following class in the application to communicate with the windows service:

```
public class Program
{
    public int Setting { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ISettingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SetSetting(int setting);
}

public class SettingService : ISettingService
{
    private readonly Program program;

    public SettingService(Program program)
    {
        this.program = program;
    }

    public void SetSetting(int setting)
    {
        program.Setting = setting;
    }
}

internal class CustomInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
{
    private readonly Program program;

    public CustomInstanceProvider(Program program)
    {
        this.program = program;
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        return GetInstance(instanceContext);
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return new SettingService(program);
    }

    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {
        IDisposable disposable = instance as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

internal class CustomInstanceProviderBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    private readonly IInstanceProvider instanceProvider;

    public CustomInstanceProviderBehaviorAttribute(IInstanceProvider instanceProvider)
    {
        this.instanceProvider = instanceProvider;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher cd in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in cd.Endpoints)
            {
                if (!ed.IsSystemEndpoint)
                {
                    ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = instanceProvider;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }
    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) { }
}

public class CustomServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    private readonly Program p;

    public CustomServiceHost(Program program, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
    : base(typeof(SettingService), baseAddresses)
    {
        this.p = program;
    }

    protected override void OnOpening()
    {
        Description.Behaviors.Add(new CustomInstanceProviderBehaviorAttribute(new CustomInstanceProvider(p)));
        base.OnOpening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip` Method to implement in your service. 
You may need to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160064.aspx).

Comment: Another interesting link I found . please have a look http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/winforms/thread/2ceda452-1576-4372-8406-a463333800f7

Comment: you are right i actually want to do that but i think window service cant interact with desktop coz of security issues. here is reference.
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx)

Comment: Then either you should not go for NotifyIcon or create two projects.A windows app and your actual service. Window App will do a limited interaction with the service and mainly it will be showing the NotifyIcon.