# C# notifyIcon: The type 'Icon' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, notifyicon

When adding a notifyIcon from Toolbox in Visual Studio and assigning an icon to it, I get the following error with the line "this.notifyIcon1.**Icon** = ((System.Drawing.**Icon**)(resources.GetObject("notifyIcon1.Icon")));" when compiling:

CS0012 "The type 'Icon' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced."

CS0234 "The type or namespace name 'Icon' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing'."

How to solve this error?

Here's the code of the *.Designer.cs file, where the error occures:

```
    private void InitializeComponent(){

        ...

        this.notifyIcon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);
        // 
        // notifyIcon1
        // 
        this.notifyIcon1.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("notifyIcon1.Icon")));
        this.notifyIcon1.Text = "notifyIcon1";
        this.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;

        ...

    }
```

Comment: Reference `System.Drawing` maybe?

Comment: Please give us *much* more context about your project: what kind of project is it, what framework(s) are you targeting, what's the project file format?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-Bit) 17.2.5 and .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: The problem only occurs with a Windows Service Project. When starting a Windows Desktop Project, it works.

Comment: I think, here is the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857191/notify-icon-for-window-service